# If Variable has no data try another?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, variables, if-statement

I am trying to create a database feeder at the end of a wizard in android.

There will be multiple different types of titles, right now however I can only call one because I will get a null pointer exception.

```
String title = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Post Title").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
```

What I need to do is something like:

```
String title = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Post Title" if no data try = "Snow:Post Title" = if no data try "Skate:Post Title").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
```

However I'm not sure how to actually get this working I've tried lots of different if null statements but none of them seem to work for what I need since my database row is created like this.

```
 String title = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Post Title").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                String maincat = mWizardModel.findByKey("Main Category").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                String price = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);


                myDb.insertRow(title, price, maincat);
```

Here is the full code it is in an onClick

```
 mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mCurrentPageSequence.size()) {

                String title = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Post Title").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                String maincat = mWizardModel.findByKey("Main Category").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                String price = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);


                myDb.insertRow(title, price, maincat);

                DialogFragment dg = new DialogFragment() {
                    @Override
                    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                .setMessage(R.string.submit_confirm_message)
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.submit_confirm_button, null)
                                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                                .create();
                    }

                };
                dg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "place_order_dialog");
            } else {
                if (mEditingAfterReview) {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                } else {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Edit: Plot twist! this code only returns the last try in its sequence (check my comments)

```
mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mCurrentPageSequence.size()) {
```

//starts sequence

```
                Bundle t = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Post Title").getData();
                if ( t != null )
                {
                    t = mWizardModel.findByKey("Snow:Post Title").getData();
                }
                if ( t != null )
                {
```

//only returns this Key! ("Skate:Post Title") none of the others.

```
                    t = mWizardModel.findByKey("Skate:Post Title").getData();
                }
                String title = t.getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);


                Bundle p = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData();
                if ( p != null )
                {
                    p = mWizardModel.findByKey("Snow:Price").getData();
                }
                if ( p != null )
                {
                    p = mWizardModel.findByKey("Skate:Price").getData();
                }
                String price = p.getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);

                String maincat = mWizardModel.findByKey("Main Category").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);


                myDb.insertRow(title, price, maincat);

                DialogFragment dg = new DialogFragment() {
                    @Override
                    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                .setMessage(R.string.submit_confirm_message)
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.submit_confirm_button, null)
                                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                                .create();
                    }

                };
                dg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "place_order_dialog");
            } else {
                if (mEditingAfterReview) {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                } else {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier (and probably work) if you split it into separate lines:

```
/* not sure what the type is, so let's go with Data... */
Data d = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Post Title").getData();
if ( d == null )
{
    d = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Post Title").getData();
}
if ( d == null )
{
   //...
}
String title = d.getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
```

Comment: 11-21 01:37:48.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(11242): Error inserting title=null maincategory=Skate price=null
11-21 01:37:48.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(11242): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: mainTable.title may not be NULL (code 19)
you're a flippin genius it worked for 1 but not for both here is the error